# Grails 3.3.0 - g:include of controller/action that resides in a plugin

Tags: grails, gsp

In Grails 3.3.0, we are trying to use g:include of a controller and action for a controller/action that is in a local plugin.

However, Grails is no longer finding this and throwing an exception.

Comment: What do you mean by "local plugin"?  And, can you go to the controller and action directly, even if it doesn't work perfectly?  (As in, is it really there at all, in your deployed code?)

Comment: By "local plugin", I mean an in-lined one that is co-resident with the main application - in build.gradle for main project, it has something like this:      compile project(":common"). And yes, I can navigate directly to the controller/action in deployed version. It's just not finding it for g:include.